# Procedural terrain generation with blocks

Tags: javascript, three.js, terrain, heightmap

I am using three.js to create procedurally generated terrain using Perlin Noise.

I am creating the terrain using a series of blocks, but their heights along their borders are not corresponding to one another as you can see below.

How should I approach matching the height maps across blocks?

[image: terrain blocks]

I'm using Perlin Noise Algorithm for generating heights; the problem is that the height of each point is indipendent from the heights of the near points. I've other noise algorithm, but i have the same problem..

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to ask a good question. Also, showing the code you've tried will help others answer your question better.

Comment: You need to show us how you are doing it now. How are you generating the noise? noise2d? noise3d? [HERE](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/perlin_noise_3d_vertex.html) is a quick demo of noisy vertex displacement i did, maybe it helps?

Answer (score 2):

There's a really good video on infinite terrain here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk

It's in processing, but the same concept can be applied to whichever noise library you're using - I'm going to assume that you're using Perlin noise. In which case, you need to look at the values you're passing into this function and change them based on how big your blocks are.

For example, imagine a 3x3 grid of blocks. If your middle block is (x, y), and each block is 10x10 units in size, if you move 'north' (for lack of a better term), you'd need to be getting (x, y - 10) from your noise function.

The video explains it way better than I can, but hopefully this has helped. Without more knowledge of the function you're using I can't really give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will explain how to solve it for a single axis, x. It is then trivial to do the same for the y (z in three.js) axis.

The first step is to ensure the perlin noise is using the same random seed for each block. This will ensure that blocks share the same perlin noise map and so can transition smoothly between them.

The second part is to have a mapping between your block units and what is passed into the perlin noise function. For example your block x may be going from -512 to 512 units, so you get a height value for each x vertex by passing in -0.5 to 0.5 for each x vertex into the noise function.
E.g.
`vertextHeight = perlin(vertexX / 1024, vertextY / 1024)`

Your second block will then be offset so its edge interfaces with the first block. E.g. its x position will be +1024 more than the first block, and so will go from 512 to 1536.
So in this sense, block0 will have an x offset of 0, and block1 will have an x offset of 1024. 1024 being the block width/size in three.js units.

Finally, you need to give the same offsets to the noise function, but scaled based on the mapping described above. In this example, 512 would become 0.5 and 1536 would become 1.5 which looks like this:

```
size = 1024;
vertextHeight = perlin((vertexX + offsetX) / size, (vertextY + offsetY) / size)`
```

Therefore, the x value given to the noise function at the edge between block0 and block 1 will be the same, and so will return the same height value.